# Javascript excecution in firefox 3.5

Tags: javascript

I have the following piece of code :

```
var number_of_div = "";
number_of_div ="<div id='test1'>";
number_of_div +="<span id='test2'></span>"
number_of_div +="<img src='test3.jpg' />"
number_of_div +="</div>";

var holder = document.getElementById("holder");
holder.innerHTML=number_of_div;
```

The above code runs perfect in firefox 2.0.0.20
But in firefox 3.5, text inside span tags & image loads partially.

Is innerHTML causing some problem ??

Comment: what is "text inside span tags & image loads partially" ?

Comment: content of span tag, for eg., <span id='test2'>try 1</span> in this case, 'try' loads first in the browser then '1' comes up & in the same way image loads half & then appears fully

Comment: do you have Firebug ? - if yes , is there any error ? if no install it and see "if yes" section

Comment: yes i have a firebug, there is no error

Comment: do you run this piece more than one time ?

Comment: It runs perfect in other firefox versions, but my requirement is to run the above code in firefox 3.5

Comment: Wow. you're testing in FF2.0 and FF3.5 ???? The only question I can ask is *WHY?????* Do you seriously have users running FF2? Current version is FF5. FF2 has been obsolete for years, and FF3.5 users should have upgraded to 3.6 for security reasons by now, even if they didn't want to move on to v4 or 5 yet.

Comment: My code is going to be deployed on firefox 3.5 on embedded system & we need to deploy on this version only because we still don't have firefox 3.6/4/ 5 loadable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like firefox bug or something like this - try this

```
holder.innerHTML = '';
holder.appendChild( document.createTextNode( number_of_div ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to mask these differences by using a javascript library which supports all major browsers such as jQuery.

Comment: how can i mask the differences ?? is there any function which can make my life easy ??

Comment: jQuery : `$("#myElementId").html("my inner html text");` :)

Comment: Hey, this won't mark difference. This is just a way to insert content into DOM :)